# ¿ Como llamar un evento de js en un slect?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

estoy comenzando en la programacion y en el trabajo intento ayudar en lo que puedo en un aplicacion web que estan creando con ruby, hay muchas cosas que no entiendo asi que disculpen si es algo muy basico, lo que necesito es llamar un evento cuando seleccionen en la lista de estads "vigente sin fecha", para que este oculte el div en el que se encuentra la fecha, pero no esta llamando al evento de js

```
 <div class="pure-control-group">
<%= label_tag :status, "Estado"%>
<%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['Vigente', 'Vigente'], ['Vencido', 'Vencido'], ['Pendiente', 'Pendiente'], ['A vencer', 'A vencer'], ['Antiguo', 'Antiguo'], ['Vigente Sin fecha', 'Vigente Sin fecha']]), {:onChange => "hideDate();"}) %>
```

¿ como seria la correcta sintaxis del onchange ?

asi se ve el elemento select con la pagina ya renderizada

```
<select name="expiration[status]" id="expiration_status"><option value="Vigente">Vigente</option>
<option value="Vencido">Vencido</option>
<option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
<option value="A vencer">A vencer</option>
<option value="Antiguo">Antiguo</option>
<option value="Vigente Sin fecha">Vigente Sin fecha</option></select>
```

el evento de js todavia no tiene la programacion final, por ahora lo uso para verificar si llama de manera correcta al evento, esto lo hago cambiando el valor de un p para que muestre la fecha

```
 <script>
     function hideDate() {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date();
     }
     </script>
     <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Ya en la página renderizada en el navegador web, haz click en la lista desplegable de estands y seleccionas "inspeccionar elemento" y escribe aquí lo que se muestra (sólo el select que se muestra, lo demás no nos interesa) para saber si se está renderizando como se espera.  También muestra tu archivo js donde creas la función hideDate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al revisar el código que se renderizó observamos que no aparece el evento onChange, lo que quiere decir que hay algo mal en los parámetros que le pasaste al helper select:

```
<select name="expiration[status]" id="expiration_status">
```

La documentación de rails dice esto:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Aquí vemos que estás colocando el onChange donde debería ir options y no en html_options.

Falta colocar un hash vacío para la opción options.  Cambia la línea por:

```
<%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['Vigente', 'Vigente'], ['Vencido', 'Vencido'], ['Pendiente', 'Pendiente'], ['A vencer', 'A vencer'], ['Antiguo', 'Antiguo'], ['Vigente Sin fecha', 'Vigente Sin fecha']]), {}, {:onChange => "hideDate();"}) %>
```

Comment: te agradezco mucho por la ayuda!